# Using Soap in PHP with Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, soap

I'm developing a website which needs to use SOAP.
I'm just trying to get create a SoapClient but it's not working:

```
echo "trying soap";
$url = 'http://sscweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/WS/ssc/2/SatelliteSituationCenterService?wsdl';
$px = new SoapClient($url);
echo "soap is working";
```

It's working just fine on my localhost development environment but it's not working when I deploy my application Online.

Comment: could you fix the problem.I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, SOAP should work once sockets is released.  That'll be coming out in the next release, which will be quite soon.  See pre-release notes: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/IzEMtLMTfTg

Comment: Actually it's out in this release.

Answer (score -2):

You are using SoapClient which is inside SOAP extension. And SOAP extension has not been installed on you production servers.

Just install it, or contact your server's admin to do it for you.
Or if it's not possible, then use other library.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/ for example.

Comment: Actually i've mentioned in my question that i'm "Using Google App Engine". That's my production server. Also, there's no concept of "installing a php extension there". I've read the documentation and i've come across a section of enabled functions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions

It states there that "Soap" is enabled. But I can't seem to use it.